# Alfresco node-browser.get.js webscript

Tags: browser, nodes, alfresco

At this location in this jar file `alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d.jar\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\slingshot\node-browser\` there is a webscript. But this webscript consist to 2 files (`node-browser.get.desc.xml` and `node-browser.get.json.ftl` ) There isn't the node-browser.get.js file.

I want to know what is done in this fil. I want to select categories  and include certains aspects (i have added to categories) in the selection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript file is not mandatory while creating webscript.

Below is the URL of source file which is getting called on your specified webscript.

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V5.0.d/root/projects/remote-api/source/java/org/alfresco/slingshot/web/scripts/NodeBrowserScript.java

Below is context file for java file.

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V5.0.d/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml

check bean with `webscript.org.alfresco.slingshot.node-browser.node-browser.get`
Id.

you need to change in that if you want to customize it.

Comment: Hi Krutik
This is what i was looking for. 
But how can i modify java this java class ?

Comment: There will be one bean which is pointing to this java file.You need to modify that.

Comment: https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V5.0.d/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml is context file for that bean

Comment: Hi Krutik. 
If I manually add the file node-browser.get.js to the jar, should i access to the results returned by NodeBrowserScript.java ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a webscript is made of 3 parts:

- a description file (in your case `node-browser.get.desc.xml`) which
  uses a [description language](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/api-wsdl-webscript-descriptor-language-reference.html) to define many aspects of the
  webscript, like security, transaction management and so on
- a Server-Side Javascript js file that consists of the business logic that is performed by
  the script. In your case you don't have the `node-browser.get.js` file
  because this happens to be a Java backed webscript, that is a
  webscript whose business logic is written in Java and not in
  Server-Side Javascript.
- a Freemarker Template file, `node-browser.get.json.ftl`, which contains
  the presentation logic (view) that has to show the results of the invocation.

In order to achieve what you're looking for about selecting categories and include certains aspects, you'd better learn more about how webscripts work and moreover how to configure/customize Alfresco's interface.

You'd better look at these [tutorials](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ws-tutorials.html) in order to get more info.